# right codec for json file with 2 language

Tags: python, json, encoding, scrapy, web-crawler

I am crawling a page with `scrapy` and I want to save the response in a **JSON** file. The data has different codec (Persian and English). For Persian, encoding with UTF-8 works fine but when there are English words between Persian words that throws me an error:

> UTF-8 codec can't encode characters in position 6315-6316: surrogates
> not allowed.

I have to encode my file because Persian words show  as numbers without encoding. Here's my JSON file:

```
import json
x = [
{"text": "\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u06cc \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627 \u0648 \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0646\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u0647 \u0646\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u0634 \u0632\u0646\u062f\u06af\u06cc \u0627\u0641\u0631\u0627\u062f\u06cc \u0645\u06cc \u067e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0632\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u0634\u0647\u0631 \u0647\u0627 \u0648 \u0631\u0648\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u06a9\u0648\u0686\u06a9 \u0628\u0647 \u062f\u0646\u06cc\u0627 \u0645\u06cc \u0622\u0646 \u0648 \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u0645\u06a9\u0627\u0646\u0627\u062a \u0648 \u062e\u062f\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0634\u0627\u06cc\u0633\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u06cc \u0628\u0631\u062e\u0648\u0627\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0631 \u0646\u06cc\u0633\u062a\u0646\u062f \u060c \u06a9\u0633\u06cc \u0628\u0647\u0634\u0648\u0646 \u0627\u0647\u0645\u06cc\u062a \u0646\u0645\u06cc\u062f\u0647 \u0648 \u062f\u0631\u062f \u0647\u0627 \u0648 \u0631\u0646\u062c \u0647\u0627\u0634\u0648\u0646 \u0647\u06cc\u0686\u0648\u0642\u062a \u062f\u0631\u06a9 \u0648 \u0641\u0647\u0645\u06cc\u062f\u0647 \u0646\u0645\u06cc\u0634\u0647 . \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u0628\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0631\u06cc \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0647 \u0648 \u0634\u062e\u0635\u06cc\u062a \u0647\u0627 \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0647 \u0645\u062e\u0627\u0637\u0628 \u0646\u0632\u062f\u06cc\u06a9 \u0645\u06cc \u06a9\u0646\u0647 \u0648 \u0645\u062e\u0627\u0637\u0628 \u0631\u0648 \u0628\u0647 \u06af\u0648\u0646\u0647 \u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u062f\u0631 \u0631\u0648\u0627\u06cc\u062a \u0631\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u06cc \u06a9\u0646\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u062e\u0648\u062f\u0634 \u0631\u0648 \u062f\u0631\u0648\u0646 \u0641\u0636\u0627\u06cc \u062f\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u062d\u0633\u0627\u0633 \u0645\u06cc \u06a9\u0646\u0647 \u0648 \u0627\u0646\u06af\u0627\u0631 \u0646\u0627\u0638\u0631 \u0645\u0633\u062a\u0642\u06cc\u0645 \u062f\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646\u0647 . \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc \u062c\u0631\u0645\u06cc \u0631\u0627\u0646\u0631 \u0628\u06cc \u0646\u0642\u0635\u0647 \u0648 \u062f\u0631 \u067e\u0627\u06cc\u0627\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0627\u0648\u0646 \u062d\u0633 \u0628\u0631\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631\u06cc \u0639\u062f\u0627\u0644\u062a \u0628\u0647 \u062e\u0648\u0628\u06cc \u0627\u0646\u062a\u0642\u0627\u0644 \u062f\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0645\u06cc\u0634\u0647 . 8/10"},
{"text": "\u0648\u0627\u0642\u0639\u0627 \u0627\u0632 \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0646 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u067e\u0634\u06cc\u0645\u0648\u0646 \u0634\u062f\u0645!!"},
{"text": "\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0648 \u06a9\u0627\u0645\u0644\u2026 \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc\u06af\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0627\u0632 \u0633\u062a\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0647\u0627 \u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u062a\u0627 \u062a\u0627\u0632\u0647 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0627\u0634 \u0648\u0627\u0627\u0627\u0642\u0639\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u0631\u06a9\u0647 \u0627\u06cc\u0641\u0627\u06cc \u0646\u0642\u0634 \u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0646\u2026 \u062f\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0641\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0645\u0639\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u0648 \u0647\u06cc\u062c\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0647\u2026 \u0642\u0648\u0644 \u0645\u06cc\u062f\u0645 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0627\u062d\u0633\u0627\u0633 \u067e\u0634\u06cc\u0645\u0648\u0646\u06cc \u0628\u0647\u062a\u0648\u0646 \u062f\u0633\u062a \u0646\u0645\u06cc\u062f\u0647\u2026 \u0628\u06cc \u0646\u0638\u06cc\u0631 \u0627\u062c\u0631\u0627 \u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0646"},
{"text": "\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u062f\u0642\u06cc\u0642 \u0648 \u062d\u0633\u0627\u0628 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u06cc \u0628\u0648\u062f \u0628\u0647 \u0646\u0638\u0631\u0645 \u062c\u0632\u0648\u0647 5 \u062a\u0627 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0628\u0631\u062a\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u0644 \u0628\u0648\u062f \u0648\u0644\u06cc \u0628\u0647 \u062d\u0642\u0634 \u0646\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u062f 8/10"},
{"text": "\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u06cc \u062e\u0648\u0628 \u0648 \u0646\u062c\u06cc\u0628 \u0627\u0632 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0628\u06cc\u200c\u0627\u062f\u0639\u0627. \u0632\u06cc\u0627\u062f \u062f\u0631 \u0645\u0648\u0631\u062f\u0634 \u0628\u0648\u0642 \u0648 \u06a9\u0631\u0646\u0627 \u0646\u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0646\u062f \u0627\u0645\u0627 \u0647\u06cc\u0686\u200c\u200c\u0686\u06cc\u0632\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u06a9\u06cc\u0641\u06cc\u062a \u062e\u0648\u0628 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u06a9\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0647 \u0646\u0645\u06cc\u200c\u0634\u0647. \u0645\u0648\u0633\u0642\u06cc \u0645\u062a\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0631\u0648 \u0648\u0642\u062a\u06cc \u00ab\u0646\u06cc\u06a9 \u06a9\u0650\u06cc\u0648\u00bb \u0639\u0632\u06cc\u0632 \u062a\u0646\u0638\u06cc\u0645 \u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0634\u0647 \u06cc\u0639\u0646\u06cc \u0645\u062a\u0646 \u0648 \u062a\u0635\u0648\u06cc\u0631 \u0648 \u0645\u0648\u0633\u06cc\u0642\u06cc \u06a9\u0627\u0645\u0644\u0627\u064b \u0647\u0645\u0627\u0647\u0646\u06af \u0628\u0627 \u0647\u0645 \u062f\u0631 \u062d\u0627\u0644 \u067e\u06cc\u0634\u0631\u0648\u06cc \u0647\u0633\u062a\u0646\u062f. \u0641\u0636\u0627\u06cc \u062e\u0627\u06a9\u0633\u062a\u0631\u06cc \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0648 \u062d\u0648\u0635\u0644\u06c0 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627 \u0628\u0648\u062f. \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u062f\u0642\u06cc\u0642\u0627\u064b \u0647\u0645\u0627\u0646 \u06af\u0627\u0645\u06cc \u0631\u0648 \u062f\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0637\u06cc \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u06a9\u0646\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u062e\u0648\u062f \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0632 \u0633\u0627\u0644 1996 \u062a\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0646 \u0634\u0631\u0648\u0639 \u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0647 \u0648 \u062f\u0631 \u062d\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u062f\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u062f\u0627\u062f\u0646\u0634\u0647. \u0627\u0645\u0627 \u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062f \u0642\u0628\u0644 \u0627\u0632 \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0646 \u0647\u0631 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0627\u0646\u062a\u0638\u0627\u0631\u0645\u0648\u0646 \u0631\u0648 \u0627\u0632 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u062a\u0639\u06cc\u06cc\u0646 \u06a9\u0646\u06cc\u0645. \u0634\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0631\u0648 \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u0634\u0646\u0627\u0633\u06cc\u0645 \u0648 \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u062f\u0648\u0646\u06cc\u0645 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u0627 \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u0645\u0634 \u06af\u0632\u06cc\u0646\u06c0 \u062f\u0627\u0646\u0644\u0648\u062f \u0631\u0648 \u0627\u0646\u062a\u062e\u0627\u0628 \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u06a9\u0646\u06cc\u0645. \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u0648\u0646 \u062f\u0633\u062a \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u0647\u0633\u062a\u0634 \u06a9\u0647 \u0637\u06cc \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u062f\u0648 \u062f\u0647\u0647 \u0646\u0645\u0648\u062f\u0627\u0631 \u0622\u062b\u0627\u0631\u0634 \u067e\u06cc\u0634\u0631\u0641\u062a \u0631\u0648 \u0646\u0634\u0648\u0646 \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u062f\u0646. \u067e\u0633 \u0628\u0628\u06cc\u0646\u06cc\u062f \u0648 \u0644\u0630\u062a \u0628\u0628\u0631\u06cc\u062f."},
{"text": "\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u0648 \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0645 \u060c \u062f\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u0635\u0631\u06cc\u062d \u0648 \u0633\u0631 \u0631\u0627\u0633\u062a\u06cc \u062f\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0648\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u067e\u06cc\u0686\u06cc\u062f\u06af\u06cc \u0648 \u0645\u0639\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u0646\u06cc\u0633\u062a \u06a9 \u0628\u062e\u0648\u0627\u062f \u0630\u0647\u0646\u0648 \u062f\u0631\u06af\u06cc\u0631 \u06a9\u0646\u0647"},
{"text": "\u0628\u0647 \u0646\u0638\u0631 \u0645\u0646 \u06cc\u06a9\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u0628\u0647\u062a\u0631\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u0627\u06cc 2017 \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0647! \u0648 \u063a\u0645 \u0627\u0646\u06af\u06cc\u0632\u062a\u0631\u06cc\u0646! \u0627\u06af\u0647 \u062e\u0648\u0628 \u0628\u0647\u0634 \u0641\u06a9\u0631 \u06a9\u0646\u06cc\u0646 \u062e\u06cc\u0644\u06cc \u062f\u0631\u062f\u0646\u0627\u06a9\u0647! \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc \u0641\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0632\u0627\u0628\u062a \u0627\u0648\u0644\u0633\u0646 \u0648 \u062c\u0631\u0645\u06cc \u0631\u0646\u0631"},
{"text": "\u06cc\u06a9 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0645\u0639\u0645\u0648\u0644\u06cc \u0628\u0627 \u0631\u0648\u0646\u062f \u0636\u0639\u06cc\u0641 \u0628\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u062b\u0646\u0627\u06cc \u0622\u062e\u0631 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645"},
{"text": "\u062f\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u062e\u0648\u0628 \u060c \u0644\u0648\u06a9\u06cc\u0634\u0646 \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0637\u0648\u0631\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u0628\u0647 \u0641\u0636\u0627\u06cc \u062f\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u0634\u0628\u06cc\u0647 \u0628\u0648\u062f \u060c \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc \u062e\u0648\u0628 \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc\u06af\u0631\u0627 \u0647\u0645\u06cc\u0646 \u062a\u0639\u0631\u06cc\u0641\u0627 \u06a9\u0627\u0641\u06cc\u0647 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u06a9\u0647 \u0627\u0632 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0644\u0630\u062a \u0628\u0628\u0631\u06cc \u0648 \u0628\u0647 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0622\u06cc\u0646\u062f\u0647 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u062b\u0631 \u060c Taylor Sheridan \u060c \u0627\u0645\u06cc\u062f\u0648\u0627\u0631 \u0628\u0634\u06cc."},
{"text": "\u062f\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0645\u0639\u0631\u06a9\u0647! \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0647 \u0641\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647! \u0646\u0642\u0634 \u0627\u0641\u0631\u06cc\u0646\u06cc \u0628\u0633\u06cc\u0627\u0631 \u062f\u0631\u062e\u0634\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0632\u0627\u0628\u062a \u0627\u0648\u0644\u0633\u0646 \u0648 \u062c\u0631\u0645\u06cc \u0631\u0646\u0631! \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 wind river \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0647 \u0634\u062f\u062a \u0628\u0647 \u0647\u0645\u0647 \u067e\u06cc\u0634\u0646\u0647\u0627\u062f \u0645\u06cc \u06a9\u0646\u0645!"},
{"text": "\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0648\u0627\u0642\u0639\u0627 \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0628\u0648\u062f \u0647\u06cc\u062c\u0627\u0646 \u0632\u06cc\u0627\u062f \u0646\u062f\u0627\u0634\u062a \u0648\u0644\u06cc \u062e\u0648\u0634 \u0633\u0627\u062e\u062a \u0628\u0648\u062f \u0648 \u0628\u06cc\u0646\u0646\u062f\u0647 \u0631\u0648 \u0645\u062d\u0648 \u062e\u0648\u062f\u0634 \u0645\u06cc\u06a9\u0646\u0647 \u0635\u062d\u0646\u0647 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0637\u0628\u06cc\u0639\u06cc \u0632\u0645\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u0641\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0632\u06cc\u0628\u0627 \u0647\u0633\u062a\u0646 \u067e\u06cc\u0634\u0646\u0647\u0627\u062f \u0645\u06cc\u06a9\u0646\u0645 \u062d\u062a\u0645\u0627 \u0628\u0627 \u06a9\u06cc\u0641\u06cc\u062a \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0627 \u0628\u0628\u06cc\u0646\u06cc\u062f \u062a\u06cc\u062a\u0631\u0627\u0698 \u067e\u0627\u06cc\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0641\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0628\u0648\u062f \u0628\u0627 \u0627\u0648\u0646 \u0645\u0648\u0633\u06cc\u0642\u06cc \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0628\u0628\u06cc\u0646\u06cc\u062f \u0648 \u0644\u0630\u062a \u0628\u0628\u0631\u06cc\u062f"},
{"text": "\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u062e\u0648\u0628\u06cc\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc \u0631\u0646\u0631 \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc.\u0641\u0642\u0637 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u06cc\u06a9\u0645 \u0633\u0631\u0631\u0627\u0633\u062a \u0648 \u0641\u0627\u0642\u062f \u067e\u06cc\u0686\u06cc\u062f\u06af\u06cc \u062e\u0627\u0635\u06cc\u0647.\u06cc\u06a9\u0645 \u0645\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0631 \u0645\u06cc\u062f\u0627\u062f\u0646 \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u0648\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a\u062e\u0648\u0646 \u062e\u0648\u0631\u062f \u06a9\u0646 \u0645\u06cc\u0634\u062f.\u062f\u0631 \u06a9\u0644 \u0628\u0647 \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0646\u0634 \u0645\u06cc \u0627\u0631\u0632\u0647 \u0648\u0644\u06cc \u0627\u0646\u062a\u0638\u0627\u0631 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u06cc \u0645\u062b\u0644\u0627 \u0645\u062b\u0644 prisoner \u0646\u062f\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0634\u06cc\u062f."},
{"text": "\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u062f\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u0644 2015 \u0628\u0627 sicario \u0645\u0634\u0647\u0648\u0631 \u0634\u062f \u0648 \u0628\u0627 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u062a\u062d\u0633\u06cc\u0646 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u06cc Hell or High Water \u062f\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u0644 2016 \u062e\u0648\u062f \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0647 \u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u06cc\u06a9 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u062c\u062f\u06cc \u0645\u0637\u0631\u062d \u0646\u0645\u0648\u062f\u0648 \u062d\u0627\u0644\u0627 \u0628\u0627 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 wind river \u0628\u0627 \u06cc\u06a9 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0648 \u0645\u0648\u0636\u0648\u0639 \u0648 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u062e\u0648\u0628 \u0637\u0631\u0641 \u0647\u0633\u062a\u06cc\u0645. \u062a\u0648\u0635\u06cc\u0647 \u0645\u06cc \u06a9\u0646\u0645 \u062d\u062a\u0645\u0627 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0631\u0627 \u0628\u0628\u06cc\u0646\u06cc\u062f."},
{"text": "miraziz \u0639\u0632\u06cc\u0632 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u0647\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u06af\u0641\u062a\u06cc \u0647\u0631 \u06a9\u062f\u0648\u0645 \u0631\u0648 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0647 \u0627\u06cc \u0633\u0627\u062e\u062a\u0646\u062f : sicario \u0631\u0648 Denis Villeneuvem \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u06a9\u0631\u062f\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u0627\u062a\u0641\u0627\u0642\u0627 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u0633\u0631\u0634\u0646\u0627\u0633\u06cc \u0647\u0633\u062a \u0648 \u0642\u0628\u0644 \u0627\u0632 sicario \u0647\u0645 \u0686\u0647\u0627\u0631\u062a\u0627 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0641\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0646\u06cc \u062f\u0627\u0631\u0647 Prisoners 2013 \u061b Enemy 2013 \u061b Incendies 2010 \u0648 Polytechnique 2009 \u061b \u0647\u0631 \u06a9\u062f\u0648\u0645 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639 \u062e\u0648\u062f\u0634\u0648\u0646 \u062e\u0648\u0634 \u062f\u0631\u062e\u0634\u06cc\u062f\u0646\u062f \u0648 \u0645\u0646 \u0628\u0647 \u0634\u062e\u0635\u0647 Incendies \u0648 \u067e\u0644\u06cc \u062a\u06a9\u0646\u06cc\u06a9 \u0631\u0648 \u062e\u06cc\u0644\u06cc \u062f\u0648\u0633\u062a \u062f\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0645 \u0648 \u0686\u0646\u062f\u0628\u0627\u0631\u06cc \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0645 \u0647\u0631 \u06a9\u062f\u0648\u0645 \u0631\u0648 . \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 Hell or High water i \u0647\u0645 \u062f\u06cc\u0648\u06cc\u062f \u0645\u06a9\u0646\u0632\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a \u0646\u0647 \u0634\u0631\u06cc\u062f\u0627\u0646 ."},
{"text": "\u0646\u0647 \u0639\u0632\u06cc\u0632 . \u0646\u0648\u06cc\u0633\u0646\u062f\u0647 \u0648 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u062e\u0648\u062f \u062a\u06cc\u0644\u0648\u0631 \u0634\u0631\u06cc\u062f\u0646 \u0628\u0648\u062f . \u0648\u0644\u06cc \u062f\u0648 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0642\u0628\u0644\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u062a\u0648 \u06af\u0641\u062a\u06cc \u0641\u0642\u0637 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0646\u0648\u06cc\u0633\u0634\u0648\u0646 \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0647 \u0646\u0647 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646 . \u0645\u06cc\u0634\u0647 \u06af\u0641\u062a \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u062a\u062c\u0631\u0628\u0647 \u0627\u0648\u0644 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646\u06cc\u0634 \u0647\u0633\u062a . \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0631\u0648 \u0628\u0628\u06cc\u0646\u06cc \u0645\u06cc\u0641\u0647\u0645\u06cc \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06af\u0631\u062f\u0627\u0646\u0634\u0648\u0646 \u0632\u0645\u06cc\u0646 \u062a\u0627 \u0622\u0633\u0645\u0648\u0646 \u0641\u0631\u0642 \u0645\u06cc\u06a9\u0646\u0647 ."},
{"text": "\u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u201c\u0631\u0648\u062f\u062e\u0627\u0646\u0647 \u0648\u06cc\u0646\u062f\u201d \u06a9\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u0645 \u0622\u0646 \u0628\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u0632 \u0645\u0646\u0637\u0642\u0647\u200c\u0627\u06cc \u062f\u0631 \u0622\u0645\u0631\u06cc\u06a9\u0627\u06cc \u0634\u0645\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a\u060c \u0645\u062d\u0644\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a \u06a9\u0647 \u062d\u0648\u0627\u062f\u062b \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u062f\u0631 \u0622\u0646 \u0627\u062a\u0641\u0627\u0642 \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u0627\u0641\u062a\u062f. \u0645\u0646\u0637\u0642\u0647\u200c\u0627\u06cc \u062e\u0644\u0648\u062a \u0628\u0627 \u0633\u0631\u0645\u0627\u06cc \u0633\u0648\u0632\u0627\u0646 \u06a9\u0647 \u0627\u0645\u0646\u06cc\u062a \u0622\u0646 \u0686\u0646\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u062a\u0648\u0633\u0637 \u062f\u0648\u0644\u062a \u0645\u0648\u0631\u062f \u062a\u0648\u062c\u0647 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631 \u0646\u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u0633\u062a. \u0641\u0636\u0627\u06cc \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0686\u0646\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u0634\u0644\u0648\u063a \u0646\u06cc\u0633\u062a \u0648 \u062f\u0631 \u0632\u0645\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u06a9\u0647 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u0628\u0631\u0642\u0647\u0631\u0645\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0648 \u0633\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0645\u200c\u06a9\u0646\u0646\u062f\u0647 \u062a\u0639\u062f\u0627\u062f\u0634\u0648\u0646 \u0632\u06cc\u0627\u062f \u0634\u062f\u0647\u060c \u06a9\u0645\u062a\u0631 \u0627\u0632 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0646\u0648\u0639 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u200c\u0647\u0627 \u0631\u0648 \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u0628\u06cc\u0646\u06cc\u0645. \u0644\u0648\u06a9\u06cc\u0634\u0646\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0637\u0628\u06cc\u0639\u06cc \u0648 \u0622\u0647\u0633\u062a\u0647 \u067e\u06cc\u0634 \u0631\u0641\u062a\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u06a9\u0627\u0645\u0644\u0627 \u0645\u062e\u0627\u0637\u0628 \u0631\u0648 \u0628\u0627 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0647\u0645\u0631\u0627\u0647 \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u06a9\u0646\u0647. \u062a\u0635\u0648\u06cc\u0631 \u0647\u0645 \u062c\u0627\u06cc \u062e\u06cc\u0644\u06cc \u0627\u0632 \u062f\u06cc\u0627\u0644\u0648\u06af\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0631\u0648 \u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0648 \u0628\u0647 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0635\u0648\u0631\u062a \u0645\u06cc\u0634\u0647 \u0628\u0627 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06a9\u062a\u0631\u0647\u0627 \u0647\u0645\u0630\u0627\u062a\u200c\u067e\u0646\u062f\u0627\u0631\u06cc \u06a9\u0631\u062f. \u062f\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0628\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u0632 \u06cc\u06a9 \u0648\u0627\u0642\u0639\u06cc\u062a \u0647\u0633\u062a \u0648 \u0686\u0646\u062f\u0627\u0646 \u0647\u0645 \u062e\u0627\u0635 \u0646\u06cc\u0633\u062a \u0627\u0645\u0627 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645\u200c\u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0627\u06cc\u0646\u0642\u062f\u0631 \u062e\u0648\u0628 \u0633\u0627\u062e\u062a\u0647 \u0648 \u067e\u0631\u062f\u0627\u062e\u062a\u0647 \u0634\u062f\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u0647\u0645 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0645\u0639\u0645\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u0648 \u0647\u0645 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u06a9\u0634\u0646 \u0648 \u062c\u0646\u0627\u06cc\u06cc \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0646\u0634 \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0647. \u062c\u0646\u0628\u0647 \u0631\u0648\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0648 \u0645\u0634\u06a9\u0644\u0627\u062a \u062f\u0631\u0648\u0646\u06cc \u0647\u0645 \u062a\u0648 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0628\u0631\u0631\u0633\u06cc \u0645\u06cc\u0634\u0647. \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc \u201c\u062c\u0631\u0645\u06cc \u0631\u0646\u0648\u201d \u0641\u0648\u0642\u200c\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0647 \u0648 \u06a9\u0644\u0627 \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc \u0647\u0645\u0647 \u06a9\u0627\u0631\u06a9\u062a\u0631\u0647\u0627 \u0642\u0627\u0628\u0644 \u0642\u0628\u0648\u0644 \u0647\u0633\u062a. \u0628\u0646\u0638\u0631\u0645 \u0627\u06cc\u0631\u0627\u062f \u062e\u0627\u0635\u06cc \u0628\u0647 \u0641\u06cc\u0644\u0645 \u0648\u0627\u0631\u062f \u0646\u06cc\u0633\u062a \u0648 \u0647\u0645\u06cc\u0646 \u0628\u0627\u0639\u062b \u0645\u06cc\u0634\u0647 \u06a9\u0647 \u062d\u0627\u0638\u0631 \u0646\u0634\u06cc\u062f \u06cc\u0647 \u0644\u062d\u0638\u0647\u200c\u0627\u0634\u0645 \u0627\u0632 \u062f\u0633\u062a \u0628\u062f\u06cc\u062f."},
{"text": "\u062a\u0648\u0636\u06cc\u062d \u0639\u0627\u0644\u06cc \u0628\u0648\u062f"},
{"text": "\u0633\u0631\u06cc\u0627\u0644 \u0642\u0634\u0646\u06af \u0648 \u0637\u0646\u0632\u06cc\u0647\ud83d\ude0d"}
]
with open ('f3.json','wb') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(x,ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf'))
```

i tried uft-16 but is did not work.

Comment: Please show the exception entire exception instead of just describing it.

Comment: Also, does the example in this question actually reproduce the problem? If not, please post one that does. (And ideally something shorter than this.) See the [mcve] page in the help for how to construct a good example.

Comment: Anyway, there are two common reasons for this problem: (1) JSON does not allow astral characters (`U+10000` and beyond) to be directly included in UTF-8 strings; instead, you have to encode them to surrogate pairs a la UTF-16 and then encode those surrogates to UTF-8. If you just use the `json` library that isn't a problem, but if you try to build Unicode JSON strings and then UTF-8 encode them outside of that, you can create that problem. (2) the characters `U+2028` and `U+2029` are legal JSON, but not legal JavaScript, so some parsers will refuse to handle them unescaped.

Comment: Either one of those solutions can be avoided by just using `ensure_ascii=True` instead of `ensure_ascii=False`. Of course if you need the JSON file to be human-editable, that's probably not a good answer, but if not, it's usually the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are crawling the page with scrapy you can simply ask scrapy to generate the json file for you with:

```
scrapy crawl yourcrawler -o output.json
```

in that case scrapy will do the export and you won't have to worry about encoding.

Since Scrapy 1.2.0, a new setting `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING` is introduced. By specifying it as utf-16, JSON output will not be escaped.

That is to add in your settings.py:

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-16'
```

Take a look at [this page](http://www.scrapingauthority.com/2016/09/19/scrapy-exporting-json-and-csv/) for more information. In addition I highly suggest you to take a look at the official intro tutorial [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).